# DB2 and Oracle Sybace Drivers for IBM websphere 8.5.5.11 with JDK 8

Tags: oracle, java-8, db2, sybase, websphere-8

We are migrating applications from Websphere 8.5.5.2 to 8.5.5.11 with JDK 8.
We connecting 3 different databases Oracle,DB2,Sybase and currently using following drivers for the same.

DB2: db2jcc.jar,db2jcc_license_cu.jar,db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
Oracle: ojdbc14.jar
Sybase:jconn4.jar

Dose this drivers will support JDK 8 or do we need to use different version of jars. We are bale to connect DB with this jars in WAS-8.5.5.11 but does this cause any connection issues when load was high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support Java-8 with Db2 jdbc , it is best to use a recent version of the Db2-driver files, at least higher than V10.5-fixpack7 or higher.

To learn which jdbc-driver-version gets supplied with which Db2-client version, check [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&uid=swg21363866). You can download latest drivers from that page (IBM registration required).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at various Oracle doc (cited below) it looks like you should plan to move up to a newer version of the Oracle JDBC driver for Java 8.

Regarding ojdbc14.jar which you were using, [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html) states that it is for JDK 1.4 and JDK 1.5

On the [Oracle JDBC faq](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html), under the section titled "What are the Oracle JDBC releases versus JDK versions?" it indicates to use ojdbc6, ojdbc7, or ojdbc8 with Java 8 depending on which Oracle database version you have.